# I wanted synchronous method for firebase firestore database in e-commerce application

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I checked some where they have mentioned synchronous method is not available at firebase so i wanted to know if I update product when someone buys it and the request of multiple user is done at a same time then can firebase handle it or i need synchronous method for it? And if i need synchronous method then how to perform it

I mean when multiple user clicks on buy mow then the database has to decrease the unit value how many user has  completed the payment will firebase firestore database able to handle it or i need synchronous method compulsory??

Comment: I don't think "synchronous" is the word you're looking for.  What is the situation that you're trying to address?  Is there a particular problem with something?

Comment: The issue likely refers to database transaction to ensure consistency, which is probably what "synchronous" means in this context. If this is the case, Firestore does fully support it.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these cases you can use

```
FieldValue.increment(ANY_NUMBER)
```

It works for both increment and decrement, for decrement just pass a negative value.
you don't have to worry about the multiple users, Firestore will handle it automatically.

You can read more about this,

[Article on Firebase Increment](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html)